# C# trying to zip a file used by another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, locked

I'm learning C# and have a problem with IO.Exception. So my little app opens a directory, checks for image files there and if it finds any that fit a predefined conditions then changes the name of the file (copy the file with a new name and then deletes the old file). The problem is that in the next step I want to take all files from that folder and put them into a zip.
If i just open the app and go directly to 'zip the files' everything works just fine, but if I open the app and first do the renaming and then try to zip files it crashes on IO Exception (files in use by another thread).

Is there a way to tell the RENAME function to stop the thread once finished so that a different function (ZIP) can access those files?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please show us what you've already done and provide us with a minimal, reproducable example of your problem

Comment: See [mcve]   -  @pythonic833 you can write `[mcve]`